# Getting JSON from Open Weather Map

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, github

I'm picking up Angular for my own education. I've been following tutorials on CodeAcademy and PluralSight (namely the *AngularJS: Get Started* stream).

I'm sorry to be awkward here but I have two errors for two different projects. I didn't want to make two new topics as they're small but I can't get my head around it.

**Unknown Error** 
I know the problem but I don't know *why* it's occurring. I searched the site here and online and tried the suggested fixes but it did nothing for me, so I reverted back to the state I had it. I'm currently learning about custom services and trying to add one for a github viewer.

The error I get is:`TypeError: github.getUser is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.search (script.js:39)`. I checked the line in the script and I can't see what is wrong (I followed it directly from the tutorial and none of the fixes online worked for me. Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/IipX8a09PzX4iUZdVutS?p=preview

I think it's an error with my dependencies but I'm not sure why!

**JSON PROBLEM**
I decided to make a wee application to pull weather data from the site openweathermap. (I seen a different weather app on TutorialsPoint and wanted to try my own).

The JSON file can be found here: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Galway,ie&mode=json

and my code can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RaMkbx1zqwlJsbZrwueQ?p=info

(It works grand when I host it locally with http-server, so I'm not sure why plnkr is giving out!)

It's when I try to access the deeper array (list), it fails to recognise anything. The upper array (city) is no bother however!

**Conclusion**
I'm trying to learn Angular so there's no time constraint or anything. Even if you could help me see why I'm wrong, I'd appreciate it greatly!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to create two separate questions since the problems are happening in two separate projects altogether.

It looks like the first issue is because of wrongly [annotating](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) the dependencies on the `MainController` - you were getting the `$http` service as the variable named `github`.

Changing the annotation on the `MainController` definition into this resolves that issue:

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", "$log", "$location","$anchorScroll", "github", MainController]);
```

Basically the named dependencies (annotations) should match the parameters on the function named `MainController` which is this:

```
var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $location, $anchorScroll, github) {
  // ....
};
```

Here is a working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/vX0AGv?p=preview

If I am able to figure out your second problem, I will add the solution into this answer.

**EDIT:** For the second issue, it looks like you did not update the path of `script.js` and `style.css` in the `index.html` when you ported your working code into Plunker

These lines seems to work ([updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2b2Mvm?p=preview))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**EDIT (5-Oct-2015):** As mentioned in the comment below, there was yet another typo that was preventing the solution to the first problem to not load the repositories from GitHub. Here is the plunk with the typo corrected: http://plnkr.co/edit/1rxqQ3?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have tried the code and the only issue is that it does not return project information now. According to the console to issue is with the 'return response.data;' I have on line 15 of github.js.

The other method works fine though (as the user name and profile picture changes) but the repositories do not load. Do you know why this is? :)

All I can see is that 'response' is not recognised but I cannot see how this can be.

Comment: There was a typo in the variable named `response` (incorrectly typed in as `reponse`). Here is the URL where it loads the repositories as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/1rxqQ3?p=preview

Comment: @Bosca - Does the updated answer help? Please accept the answer as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it does.

Comment: Sorry about that! I didn't see your message! That was indeed correct.....a bit embarrassing haha.

Thank you for your help. :) 

(I'm off to get an eye exam)

Comment: Please don't be embarrassed - been there, done that! :) Since JavaScript allows implicit declaration of variables and lacks the safety of a compiler, I recommend using the [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) as well as a static checking or "linting" of the code with something like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/). And thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An example that gets JSON data from Open Weather Map:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myVm', function($scope, $http) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.lat=37, vm.lon=35;
    vm.getWeather = function(lat, lon) {
         console.log("getWeather invoked with",lat,lon);
         if (vm.data == "pending") return ["pending"];
         var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
         vm.data = "pending";
         var p = $http.jsonp(url, { params : {
              lat : lat,
              lon : lon,
              callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
              APPID: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
         }});
         p.then (function (response) {
              vm.data = response.data;
         }).catch (function (error) {
              vm.data = "error "+error.status;
         })
         return ["GetWeather lat="+lat+" lon="+lon];
     };
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfh10e7/).